# Typescript object parameter to type

Tags: typescript

With this code `foo.bar` is of type `any`. How do I change it to type of `number`?

```js
  const foo = {} as any

  foo.bar = 4 as number
```

Comment: Why not write `const foo = { bar: 4 }`? Then the correct type is inferred. `foo` is typed as `any`, so `foo.<any>` is `any`.

Comment: This is a simplified version of my actual issue. The problem is I don't have access to the given object.

Comment: In that case you can't. Any property of an `any`-typed value is also `any`.

Comment: What if foo is without defined type?

Comment: Please [edit] to explain the actual context - if you don't supply an explicit type for `foo` its inferred type is the empty object `{}`, and you can't assign to `foo.bar` at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can define properties as optional if you are not sure which all properties will be there.

```
type Foo = {
  bar?: number
}

const foo: Foo = {}
foo.bar = 4
```